# Is there a syntactic error that I'm overlooking in this loop

Tags: c

Hey guys could you please spot the semantic error that's in the code below, it seems OK to me but my instructor claims that there still is an "syntactic" error.

This is a simple program that prints a simple series starting from 256.
The series depends on the value of the variable a which is 256 in this case.
Hence in this case the series looks like 256,16,4,2,1. */

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 256;
    int square_root_a;
    printf("%d\n", a);

repeat:
    square_root_a = sqrt(a);
    if (square_root_a >= 2)
    {
        printf("%d\n", square_root_a);
        a = square_root_a;
        goto repeat;
    }else{
        printf("%d\n", 1);

    } return 0;
}
```

Comment: It depends what (s)he means by "semantic error"... Anyway, this is an ugly use of `goto`.

Comment: And `printf("%d\n", 1);` might as well be `printf("1\n");`

Comment: Whether or not there is a semantic error depends on what exactly the code is supposed to do, and you haven't told us that.

Comment: Please tell me you're just learning `goto` as part of the assignment (and learning not to use it in 99.9% of all cases). Other than that ... who knows what "semantic" your prof has in his brain.

Comment: aix: this is a 20 lines program that computes the successives square roots of a. Reading the snippet is not that long eh?

Comment: @Gui13: Well, this is what the student has produced. The instructor claims that the student's code has a semantic error. We're being asked to find that semantic error, but we are not being told what the *original problem statement* was. I therefore don't understand the point of your comment.

Comment: @Brian Roach: In my neck of the woods, the words "syntactic" and "semantic" mean very different things. Looking at the edit history, it's not at all obvious to me why changing one to the other was at all justified. Of course I could've overlooked something.

Comment: @aix - Now I'm completely confused. If there was a *syntax* error ... the compiler would tell him.

Answer (score 2):

You declare `a` as an integer, which will round the result of `sqrt()` to the nearest integer.

I guess you're [supposed](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sqrt) to use `double`.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but a is a power of 2, so there is no rounding.

Comment: @EthanSteinberg: With respect, there are lots of powers of two that aren't perfect squares. The number `2` itself is the smallest of them all. ;-)

Comment: This is exactly what "semantic error" means: you shouldn't assume that sqrt(a) will always be an int. Changing `a` to 257 will make your program print things that are wrong. Also: fix your printf()'s when changing a to a float ;)

Comment: And without a very good reason otherwise, always prefer `double` for variables of a floating-point nature.

Comment: pmg: yep, I modified my answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it's not about the `goto`, or the int-ness of the variables, then my guess is your teacher means something subtle, like the `printf`s in both branches of the `if`. They have exactly the same purpose! Why write two statements that do the same, if it's possible to use only one? Just move the first one to above the `if`, and delete the second one.